# How to find all the id's associated with a particular class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jquery how is it possible finding out all the id's associated with a given class?

Any help??

Answer (score 3):

Loop over all of the elements with the specified class, and store their IDs in an array. See [jQuery `.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
var ids = [];
$('.class').each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('id'))
        ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/cXczN/)**

```
//This will give you ids of all the controls have the specified class
$('.className').each(function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: thanks Adil ...i just feel like opening my eyes to the world of jquery simpliciy...

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
var ids = $(".class").map(function() { 
    return this.id.length > 0 ? this.id : null; 
}).get();
```

Checking if the id.length > 0 makes sure you don't empty strings from elements without an id.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/T8YuD/

Comment: @VisioN what's the purpose of the .get() at the end of the call? It doesn't change anything from what I can tell. Could you explain it?

Comment: `get()` returns a basic JavaScript array instead of jQuery-wrapped array. Read more information in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/map/). Also you can see the difference in DEMO.

Answer (score 0):

You could use them together like `$('#id.class')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getIDs(className)
{
    var ids = [];

    $('.' + className).each(function()
    {
       var id = $(this).attr('id');
       if (id) ids.push(id);
    });
    return ids;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   function getAllIds(className){
       var results = [];
       $(className).each(function(){
              results.push($(this).attr('id'));

       });
       return results;
   }
```